# How do I get Tizen's B2B API working on the emulator? I want this for a TV

Tags: javascript, tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-studio

I'm just getting started with Tizen so I hope this is an easy noobie question, but it's got me stumped.  I'm using the emulator T-samsung-5.5-x86.  I'm trying to use Tizen's B2B API with this on my HTML page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$B2BAPIS/b2bapis/b2bapis.js"></script>
<script src="$WEBAPIS/webapis/webapis.js"></script>
    
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
```

And this in my code:

```
var speakerType = b2bapis.b2bcontrol.getSpeakerType();
```

When it runs it gives me this error when hovering over b2bapis:

*ReferenceError: b2bapis is not defined*

Also, in my Console, it says:
*b2bapis.js - Failed to load resource.*

webapis works fine for me.

Comment: Hi, I cannot start at all. Where did you get the b2bapis.js file? I have a sssp b2b account but I only find tizen studio and TV extensions in the Tools Menu...

Answer (score 1):

Just want to note here what I found.
b2bapis is working only on real smart TV not emulators.

Make sure you have added this import in your index.html

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="$B2BAPIS/b2bapis/b2bapis.js"></script>
```

also privilege in your config.xml eg. `b2bapis.b2bcontrol` importing this

```
<tizen:privilege name="http://developer.samsung.com/privilege/b2bcontrol"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh well, jeez...  So the B2BAPIS apparently aren't something that are working on the emulator (at least not mine) but once I connected to a Samsung TV work just fine.  Guess I just got by my first noob hurdle...

Comment: Do you use a specific SSSP TV model?